# Why does Brody's wife call him by his surname?

Tags: character, homeland

I don't think I've ever heard *Brody*'s wife call him *"Nicholas"* throughout the first two seasons of [*Homeland*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1796960/). Why does she always call him by his surname?

Answer (score 21):

Here is Nicolas Brody's (Damian Lewis) answer on it -

> Q. Why does the wife call him Brody?
>
> A. [Laughs] Morena’s been asking that all season. “Why don’t I call
> him Nick?” I’m a boarding-school-educated Brit so people have been
> calling me by my last name forever. So it doesn’t seem that weird to
> me. I think the writers see it as a term of endearment.
>
> (Source: [www.nytimes.com](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/12/11/arts/television/damian-lewis-of-homeland-on-showtime.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0))

By the way, it's very common for military wives to call their husband by their last  name.